# getLogoutUrl using facebook graph api php CodeIgniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am following the http://benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4-codeigniter/
Tutorial. here i can get the login url but i can not get the logout url
can anyone tell me why i an not getting this

Here is my facebook libaray logout function

```
 public function logout_url() {
        $_session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
        $session = new FacebookSession( $_session->getToken() );
        $next_url = 'http://localhost/ci_sdk/index.php/welcome/login';
        return $this->helper->getLogoutUrl($session,$next_url);         
      }
```

Here is my constructor in facebook library

```
  public function __construct() {
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->permissions = $this->ci->config->item('permissions', 'facebook');

    FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $this->ci->config->item('api_id', 'facebook'), $this->ci->config->item('app_secret', 'facebook') );


    $this->helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( $this->ci->config->item('redirect_url', 'facebook') );

    if ( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') ) {
      $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->ci->session->userdata('fb_token') );

      try {
        if ( ! $this->session->validate() ) {
          $this->session = null;
        }
      } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        // Catch any exceptions
        $this->session = null;
      }
    } else {

      try {
        $this->session = $this->helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
      } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {

      } catch( Exception $ex ) {

      }
    }

    if ( $this->session ) {
      $this->ci->session->set_userdata( 'fb_token', $this->session->getToken() );

      $this->session = new FacebookSession( $this->session->getToken() );

       $this->logoutURL = $this->helper->getLogoutUrl( $this->session, 'http://localhost/ci_sdk/index.php/welcome/login' );
    }
  }
```

Here is my controller function

```
public function logout()
    {
        $this->load->library('facebook');
        $logout_url = $this->facebook->logout_url();
        echo '<a href="' . $logout_url . '">logout</a>';

    }
```

It is giving me this errors

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getToken() on null in E:\xammp\htdocs\ci_sdk\application\libraries\facebook\facebook.php
```

I am new to CodeIgniter so kindly help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$this->facebook` doesn’t seem to contain the object you think it does, but is simply `null` instead.

Comment: @CBroe some solution will be appropriate as i said i am beginner...

Comment: Can you echo $session?